# java.lang.SecurityException: WFLYSRV0228: Security Exception

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I am trying to start Keycloak and i am getting this exception

> 2017-12-09 13:25:54,270 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) "WFLYCTL0193: Failed executing subsystem datasources boot
>   operations" 2017-12-09 13:25:54,354 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("core-service" => "management"),
>       ("security-realm" => "KChttpsRealm") ]): java.lang.SecurityException: WFLYSRV0228: Security Exception
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.retrieveFromVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:118)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.RuntimeExpressionResolver.resolvePluggableExpression(RuntimeExpressionResolver.java:45)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionString(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:331)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.parseAndResolve(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:240)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionStringRecursively(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:142)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionsRecursively(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:84)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressions(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:66)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.resolveExpressions(ModelControllerImpl.java:890)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveValue(AttributeDefinition.java:580)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveModelAttribute(AttributeDefinition.java:539)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveModelAttribute(AttributeDefinition.java:513)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler.addKeyManagerService(SecurityRealmAddHandler.java:632)
>           at org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler.execute(SecurityRealmAddHandler.java:821)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1344)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:485)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:387)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:349)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:392)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:365)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default
>   parameters
>           at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.retrieve(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:297)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.getValue(RuntimeVaultReader.java:146)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.getValueAsString(RuntimeVaultReader.java:126)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.retrieveFromVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:116)
>           ... 27 more Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1026)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
>           at org.picketbox.util.EncryptionUtil.decrypt(EncryptionUtil.java:133)
>           at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.retrieve(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:293)
>           ... 30 more
>
> 2017-12-09 13:25:54,492 INFO 
>   [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread
>   1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
>   2017-12-09 13:25:54,494 INFO 
>   [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread
>   1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Mahou' 8.1.0.Final
>   2017-12-09 13:25:54,509 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment
>   "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
>   2017-12-09 13:25:54,512 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC
>   service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default
>   suspending 2017-12-09 13:25:54,512 INFO 
>   [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0007:
>   Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8665
>   2017-12-09 13:25:54,514 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC
>   service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping 2017-12-09
>   13:25:54,520 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service
>   thread 1-4) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.3.15.Final stopping 2017-12-09
>   13:25:54,559 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner;
>   exiting. See previous messages for details. 2017-12-09 13:25:54,561
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown
>   has been requested.

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue.

**EDIT 1**
THis is Vault information in Standalaone.xml file

```
   <vault>
            <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_URL" value="/opt/keycloak/security/vault/vault.jks"/>
            <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" value="MASK-1i9etX7oX375Tzdvf8l//F"/>
            <vault-option name="KEYSTORE_ALIAS" value="initseckey"/>
            <vault-option name="SALT" value="33550336"/>
            <vault-option name="ITERATION_COUNT" value="99"/>
            <vault-option name="ENC_FILE_DIR" value="/opt/keycloak/security/vault/"/>
        </vault>
```

and this is keycloak.conf file entry

```
VAULT:vault.jks:MASK-1i9etX7oX375Tzdvf8l//F:initseckey:33550336:99
```

Comment: Seems like a vault misconfiguration in the application server. You should share more details, which server version do you use. How you create a keystore for vault, how the vault is configured in your system, ...

Comment: @kwart I added more information